# Expectation of inverse Mills ratio

Tags: mathematical-statistics, normal-distribution, expected-value

I am working on a model where the inverse Mills ratio of a gaussian distribution, i.e.

$$\lambda(x) := \frac{\phi(x)}{\Phi(x)} := \frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi}}\exp\left(-\frac{1}{2}x^2\right) \frac{1}{\Phi(x)},$$

with $\Phi(\cdot)$ being the CDF of the normal distribution, pops up. I need to compute

$$\mathbb{E} \left[ \lambda(X) \right], $$

with $X \sim \mathcal{N}\left(0,1 \right)$. Is there something known about the distribution of the inverse Mills ratio ? I did not find any answer in the existing litterature. Integration by parts allows to write the expectation as

$$\mathbb{E}\left[\log \left(\Phi (X) \right) X\right], $$

with $X \sim \mathcal{N}\left(0,1 \right)$, but I am not able to find a close form expression for this either. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**EDIT**

Some simulations ($10^4$ draws) yield the following histogram. Looks like a Gamma or Beta distribution to me.

[image: Simulations]

**EDIT**

Fitting a beta curve seems to yield the best results. Params returned by `scipy.stats.beta.fit()` are $1.4644927845589395, 5.611399144401899, -0.003399335311722968, 4.367791173845124$.

[image: Beta fit of the data]
<sub>(source: [github.io](https://linusbleistein.github.io/assets/img/betafit.jpg))</sub>

Comment: Not sure if you will find a closed-form to the integral, but the expectation numerically integrates to 0.903197 ...

Comment: My simulations yield the same value. However, the distribution of draws from the random variable whose expectation I try to compute resemble some kind of Gamma-distribution (see edit).